# Mousewheel Scroll - Change Image on scroll

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmousemove, onmouseclick

I'd like to make my images change on user-initiated mousewheel scroll. I copied and pasted the code from this website:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml

and just changed my image names. Here is their code:

```
<img id="slideshow" src="images/trial1/img-1.png" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var myimages=[
  "img-1.png",
  "img-2.png",
  "img-3.png",
  "img-4.png",
  "img-5.png"
]
var slideshow=document.getElementById("slideshow")
var nextslideindex=0
function rotateimage(e){
  var evt=window.event || e
  var delta=evt.detail? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta
  nextslideindex=(delta<=-120)? nextslideindex+1 : nextslideindex-1
  nextslideindex=(nextslideindex<0)? myimages.length-1 : (nextslideindex>myimages.length-1)? 0 : nextslideindex
  slideshow.src=myimages[nextslideindex]
  if (evt.preventDefault)
    evt.preventDefault()
  else
    return false
}
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel"

if (slideshow.attachEvent)
  slideshow.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, rotateimage)
else if (slideshow.addEventListener)
  slideshow.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, rotateimage, false)
</script>
```

For some reason, the first image loads, but then is broken on the scroll. I've triple-checked my paths and code, so I'm not sure what is going wrong. Here's the url to the page I'm trying to get the images to scroll on:

http://violetoeuvre.com/photography.html

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `images/trial1/` before img-x.png when changing path.